# Show bootbox alert in Typescript/Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

I want to use Bootbox in my Angular2 project. I searched a lot but there is no any relevant solution for me.
I also tried `angular2-modal` but there were many issues while using `angular2-modal`, please suggest any good doc/Examples/Demos for the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1:** Install bootbox via `npm install bootbox --save`

**Step 2:** If you are using systemjs then include bootbox like:

```
<script src="node_modules/bootbox/bootbox.js"></script>
```

**Step 3:** Just put `declare var bootbox:any;` after import all libreries and before component decorator in your component ts file and then use normaly like `bootbox.alert("Hello world!");` on any function call.

Make sure you have **bootstrap** and **jquery** installed and included in index page. jquery should be in first place then after bootstrap.

**[Edit]**

Alternate Step 3
Instead of `declare var bootbox:any;`, import type type definitions instead:

```
npm install @types/jquery --save
npm install @types/bootbox --save
```

Comment: what should i import in my .ts file ?

Comment: Hi @Vikas, Thanks for your answer, but after doing this i got this error:team.component.html:4:2 caused by: bootbox is not defined, Please suggest me how i define bootbox.

Comment: Thank you so much , You saved my time.  :)

Comment: instead of `declare var bootbox:any`, you can install @types/bootbox: `npm install @types/bootbox --save`

Comment: @Pixelbits, Then how I will get the reference of bootbox in my .ts file ?

Comment: you don't. the type is automatically resolved.

Comment: @pixelbits,  i tried your solution but error: "caused by: bootbox is not defined " occurred.

Comment: should I use    <script src="node_modules/bootbox/bootbox.js"></script> in my index.

Comment: after including     <script src="node_modules/bootbox/bootbox.js"></script> then its worked.

Comment: Any Idea how to do this if you are not using systemjs?

Comment: @pixelbits I am facing the similar problem but this time I am getting $.fn.modal of undefined. I am using following statement to load files
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import * bootbox from "bootbox"

Comment: Bootbox has types: npm install @types/bootbox

Comment: @MantuNigam ... try this --> "scripts": [       
         "../node_modules/bootbox/bootbox.js"       
      ] in .angular-cli.json file, after installing bootbox with npm -and dont forget to restart server

Comment: great solution. +1